accessing html fragment returned by WooCommerce wc_fragment_refresh
I’m trying to figure out how to access the html fragment returned by the min-cart template when retrieved by the WooCommerce wc_fragment_refresh event.
I’d like to update several custom attributes in cart items, including the max quantity available.
I’ve added the attributes to an element in a custom mini cart template.
How can I access the fragment returned by the wc_fragment_refresh event, so that I can then update the values in the cart?
Thanks
